# Configuring spatial plugin for neo4j

Tags: scala, neo4j, playframework-2.0, cypher, anormcypher

To learn some new things I recently started a web project based on [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org), [Play](http://www.playframework.com) and [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org).
My Play application connects to Neo4j using [AnormCypher](http://anormcypher.org).

Everything works fine, but at the moment I am struggling to implement a proximity search feature...

I know that the [Spatial Plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial) is the way to go and already installed the plugin on the Neo4j server, but I don't know which configuration steps are necessary to use it (in ordinary cypher) queries.

The relevant nodes look like this:

```
(city: Location {name: "Zürich", lat: 47.3667, lon: 8.5500})
```

Is it possible to setup everything, such that I can write something like

```
MATCH (location: Location)-[...SOME_PATTERN
WHERE location 'withinDistance:[47.3,8.5, 100.0]'
RETURN location.name
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spatial plugin still uses the legacy indexing syntax in Cypher, so you must use this sort of syntax:

```
START location=node:spatial_index_here('withinDistance:[47.3,8.5, 100.0]')
MATCH (location)-[...SOME_PATTERN
RETURN location.name
```

Comment: Ok. But how can I configure the spatial plugin to index all the nodes of type `Location` using the properties `lat` and `lon`?

Comment: You have to add them manually to the index. Spatial is still a legacy-style index, AFAIK.

Comment: Ok. But how exactly is this possible? I interact with Neo4j through your library (AnormCypher). I use something like `Cypher("""MERGE (location: Location {id: {id},  ...""").on("id"-> id, ...).execute()` to create/update the nodes that should be indexed. To add a node to de spatial index I have to do do something like: `POST http://url/of/neo4j/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodeToLayer` with body `{"layer":"geom", "node":"http://localhost:7575/db/data/node/nodeid"}`. How do I get the `nodeid` from the merged node? Or is there a better way to achieve something simmilar with AnormCypher?

Comment: Probably a good feature/pull request for AnormCypher, but yeah that's probably the best way at the moment.

Comment: I think you overlooked a part of my question.
How can I get the `nodeid`(the id of the merged node)?

Comment: Ah, yeah... you can return it after you merge it. Either return id(location) and pull it out as Long or location and pull it out as a NeoNode case class.

Comment: Something is still wrong: 
-merge `location` in to the graph and return `id(location) as nodeID` [with (Anorm-)Cypher]
-`POST {"value":"dummy","key":"dummy","uri":"http://neo4jurl/db/data/node/nodeID"}` to `http://neo4jurl/db/data/index/node/geom` [with WS]
-`POST {"layer":"geom","node":"http://neo4jurl/db/data/node/nodeID"}` to `http://neo4jurl/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addNodeToLayer` [with WS]
-`GET http://neo4jurl/db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesWithinDistance` returns the appropriate `Location` nodes, but when I use a equivalent cypher query, nothing gets returned.

Comment: It's probably time to post a new question with more info (like what your cypher query is)

Comment: [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349807/spatial-cypher-queries-dont-work)